# (SubscriptionNotFound) The subscription 'subscriptions' could not be found

Tags: python, azure-sdk-python

I am listing all available subscriptions. When calling `subscription.id` it returns:

```
/subscriptions/<subscription-id>
```

Now if I try and pass that directly into say the Azure compute library it won't accept that as an ID.

```
compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(credential=credentials, subscription_id=subscription.id)

>> (SubscriptionNotFound) The subscription 'subscriptions' could not be found.
```

This means I have to manually clean the ID

```
subscription.id.replace("/subscription/", "")
```

Which is gross. Is there an inbuilt method to get just the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the `subscription_id` attribute:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-resource/azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions.v2019_11_01.models.subscription?view=azure-python

```
from azure.mgmt.resource.subscriptions import SubscriptionClient
client = SubscriptionClient(credential)

for sub in client.subscriptions.list():
     print(sub.subscription_id)
```

(disclaimer I work at MS on the Azure SDK team)

Comment: Hi, this is what I have done, however the output for `print(sub.subscription_id)` would give me `/subscription/example-sub-id-123`, and if I wanted to then pass this into the `ComputeManagementClient` it requires I remove the prefix `/subscription/`. I was just curious if there is an inbuilt way to get just the ID section required?

Comment: `subscription_id` and `id` is not the same field, in your question you used `id`, not `subscription_id`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is **no** inbuilt method to get subscription ID by python.

You can use power shell command like `(Get-AzSubscription).SubscriptionId`.

**By [calling power shell command from Python](https://www.codecompiled.com/general/Calling+powerShell+command+from+Python/):**

> The **subprocess** module is a module in Python standard library. It
> consists of the call method which can be used to create new processes
> and receive there return values and error codes/
>
> To run a powershell command you just pass the command name to the call
> method as a string.
>
> ```
> import subprocess 
> subprocess.call("(Get-AzSubscription).SubscriptionId")
> ```

Comment: Silly question, does this require Azure CLI to be installed before running a script that does this?

Comment: Actually Azure Power Shell is what we need in this case, and it had been installed automatically most time, if not, you can install manually refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell?view=powershell-7